# MongoDB Compass throws error: Update not permitted

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am taking online class by MongoDB uni. and using a test free tier cluster. I have created a very simple collection with basic fields. Creation was successful. 5 documents. Each document has basic 8 fields as can be seen in the screenshot. The problem I am facing is I am getting error while inserting a new field called 'Number of Children(0-12 yrs)' with data type int32. This error occurring when I user data type as in32, int64, decimal128, double so far. It does not show up for string and a few other types. Being a beginner, I am not able to find more info on this error, please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBKXe.png)

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug. You can work around by entering your value as the string value and then converting it to the appropriate type.

I have filed a ticket with the Compass team. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-4300